# Qwt simpleplot example

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm using qwt 6.1.3 for some Qt plotting work and just to test I created a new project, added the library, and pasted the simpleplot.cpp example code into Qtcreator.

A copy of the file can be view here: https://github.com/eiimage/qwt/blob/master/examples/simpleplot/simpleplot.cpp

The code has returned numerous errors.

```
curve->setSymbol(symbol);
```

The above code had to have a * put before symbol to prevent an error. Though I'm not sure if this is correct.

```
curve->setSamples(points);
```

Produces the error: 'class QwtPlotCurve' has no member named 'setSamples'. However, it's used in the example and also shows up in the document for that class. What might be causing this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post all of the errors? I checked the source of `qwt_plot_curve.h` and it looks like the example is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was one of documentation. All online documentation and examples provided use the methods `setSamples` and `setRawSamples` to set the curve points. This is incorrect. The appropriate method is `setData` and `setRawData`.

Comment: How so? I've just tried with qwt 6.1.3, simpleplot example works just fine.

Comment: Must be a version issue. I'm using red hat linux, `setSamples` and `setRawSamples` literally does not exist. Everything else for plot curve is the same, I think, but the samples methods are simply not a thing.

Comment: Interesting. Looking at the source code it seems that these API are guarded by a compiler pragma: `#ifndef QWT_NO_COMPAT`. My guess is that the packages you are using are compiled with this define so these API are not included. I have no idea why though.

Comment: I thought the same thing. However, it does not explain where `setData` and `setRawData` comes from. Both of these methods are functionally identical to their samples versions. For every example program I open all instances of `setSamples` must be replaced with `setData`, otherwise there is an error. It seems strange to have two sets of functions that do the same thing. Also the simpleplot.cpp example surely uses the `QVector<QPointF>` variant, which appears after the `#endif` in the html documentation.

Comment: `setData` comes from the super class `QwtSeriesStore`. You can see the inheritance diagram [here](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_plot_curve.html). `setRawData` I have no idea. It doesn't exist in the upstream release.

I think these functions were added (or kept) to keep compatibility with some older versions.

Comment: Hey buddy. I hoped that this would be my only problem with qwt, alas it was not to be. There are some elements of the `cpuplot` example that I would like to figure out, but again I cannot run the example code. Same problem again except this time in `cpupiemarker.cpp` there is a line of code in the if statement that reads `const int value = static_cast<int>(5760*curve->sample(0).y ()/100);`. I can't find this `sample()` function in the documentation. Do you think this is another version issue?

Comment: It's a member of the `QwtSeriesStore` and documented it's [here](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/class_qwt_series_store.html#adbb86cd5cd59472f2f3137742ca74a48). Can you post the exact error? By the way are you using the distribution provided package? Maybe try building it from the source. Qwt is relatively easy to build from source, it has no dependency other than Qt.